# Unity Show/Hide menu from screen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i'm trying to show and hide a menu from a screen with mouse right click.
For example, when the right click is clicked, a menu appears and when it's pressed again, the menu hides.

```
int flag = 1;
void Update()
{
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
        {
            if(flag == 1)
            {
                RadialMenuSpawn.ins.SpawnMenu(this); //Show it
                flag = 0;
            }

            if(flag == 0)
            {
                /* hide it */
                flag = 1;
            }
        }
}
```

Is there any command to hide that menu from the screen because it's copying itself?

Comment: Okay ... good luck? What is the question?

Comment: @Bart Sorry, i have not noticed the question got deleted (might pressed a button :)). Is there any command to hide that menu from the screen because it's copying itself?.

Comment: Spawning does suggest "creation". So you don't want to do that all the time. You want to spawn/create once, and then SetActive with either true or false as an argument. If you really want to use SpawnMenu all the time, you're going to have to follow that up with a Destroy call, but I would hazard a guess that's not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply store all of your menu objects in an array and when you right click you loop through that array, enabling/disabling the objects.

```
public GameObject[] menuObjects;

private bool _menuState = false;

void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse1))
    {
        // Change the value of _menuState
        _menuState = !_menuState;

        // Loop through the menu objects
        foreach(GameObject obj in menuObjects)
        {
            // Enable/Disable the objects
            obj.SetActive(_menuState);
        }

        // Do other stuff...
    }
}
```